# Importing fab-icons with cdn in next js 13.4

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I am using next js 13.4 (latest) ,what i want to use one Icon in my project, for that i want to use the cdn for font-awesome icon so that it doesn't increase the size of app

When I am using  this,

`<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/brands.min.css" /></head>`

in my layout.js

It is creating re-hydration error

How I can fix this issue ?  Or I need to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing was happening to me, but I installed the fontawesome react LIB directly via NPM, mine was experiencing a hydration error when loading the page that contained fontawesome icons to resolve I just had to ensure that the HTML loaded was the same as the one in server what i did was add a ternary in general context { session &&  } as i had session but also putting a useEffect with empty array should work

> Error: Hydration failed because
> the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
>
> Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching svg in div.

**Solved for me:**

export function MyComponent() {

```
const [codeLoading, setCodeLoading] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
setCodeLoading(true)
}, [ ])

return(
  codeLoading && <Your HTML PAGE or Component>
)
}
```